# Why WPF DataGrid has a too large vertical scroll?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

I have a data grid with a scroll and virtualization. Everything else is fine except that there's a possibility for extra 1-23 pixels to scroll to the bottom:

[image]

I have a data grid, a custom styled scrollbar on the right and then I have a splitter on the bottom and the problem is that there is empty space between the splitter and grid, which itself is fine (as you can resize the splitter and have more empty space), but the scrollbar is now larger than it needs to be, which causes problems elsewhere. How can I make sure that the scrollbar is exactly "as tall as the content".

I don't want it to scroll to empty places, because I have code elsewhere which reads the scroll position and multiplies by the row height to determine where we are at, and it bugs as soon as you exceed the scrollable area.

The data grid looks like:

```
<DataGrid CanUserSortColumns="False"
          CanUserAddRows="False"
          CanUserDeleteRows="False"
          CanUserResizeColumns="True"
          CanUserReorderColumns="True"
          SelectionUnit="FullRow"
          ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          HeadersVisibility="Column"
          VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
          VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" />
```

**Update:** I think I know the reason. Because I use virtualization, it scrolls by one row (not by pixels), thus it won't allow me to scroll so that rows are partially visible. It always scroll by the height of a row (in my case 24 units). Now, if I move grid splitter and make the last row to be only partially visible, it correctly shows the scrollbar, but the problem is that it will scroll 24 units and thus showing empty space in the bottom.

Coming to realize that, I'm not so sure this problem can be even fixed. I just need to edit the code elsewhere to figure out if there has been exceeding scrolling, and if so, I'll "crop and ignore" the last 1-23 units of scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the property ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" on your DataGrid

For more information on this property go to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.verticalscrollbarvisibility.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help. :/ I can still scroll 1-23 px too much depending on how many pixels I've moved the grid splitter.